# attach preempt_notifier to user process in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, preemption

I am needing to identify whether a user process was ever preempted somehow, I understand we have hooks in preempt.h and sched.c which allow us to define preempt_notifiers which can in turn call sched_in and sched_out functions whenever a process is rescheduled or preempted.

But I still can't find out how can I attach a notifier to a particular process or pid in user space and then somehow log if this particular process was ever pre-empted. I'm assuming I have to write a module to do so, but how would I go about attaching a pid to a particular notifier?

Answer (score 2):

The notifier is inherently per-process. When you register it, you are registering it for the current process. See the code in `preempt_notifier_register()`, it attaches the notifer to `current->preempt_notifiers`.

Comment: Yes , that is correct , but preempt_notifier_register() can only be accessed by a kernel module , how can i determine that current is the user process that i want to have the notifier registered for. IS there a way to pin a notifier to a particular pid, i.e current.pid = my pid .

Comment: The process you want to monitor needs to call your kernel module, then `current` will be the right process.

Comment: Sorry I am new at this , so should I make a system call from user process to kernel module , how do i go about doing that ? I need a really low latency call from user process which could access the module functions.Any ideas ?

Comment: You could add a syscall, that would be one way to do it. But adding a syscall in a module is a little complicated - because the syscall may be called when the module is not loaded. Another option is to have your module create a char device and use the `ioctl()` callback as a pseduo-syscall, that is how KVM is implemented for example.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-file `/proc/<pid>/status` contains a line `nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:` which seems to be the information that you're after.

Comment: I'm not sure it does. Looking at the code in __schedule() it looks like that is also incremented when a process runs to the end of its time slice. But I could be wrong.